# Posting links to resources or posting resources

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

At `SO`,sometimes the user's question can be answered by a well labelled image then the long paragraphs of description.Images can be found by easily googling up or the blogs we follow and then posting those images in the answer(easy).Now my question is

- Is it valid to post the image from some other website to the stackoverflow.(which i think is)
- Should we care about the credits of the original creator of the resource we are posting on SO

In short,what we should prefer?

- Posting a link to the resource(*taking the creator's credits into
  account*),

**or**

- the resource itself(*thinking that  resolving the issue for the OP's
  query is our priority*).

---

This thing came up in my mind while seeing the comments under **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25183050/1228)** answer.

---

Comment: That answer you linked to is blatant plagiarism

Answer (score 3):

If you can completely answer a question by posting an image and a brief description, then there is nothing wrong with that.  Simple answers that completely answer the question are often better than extremely wordy answers.

What is an issue is not citing and providing credit for someone else's work.

1. If the image is copyrighted and you do not have permission to repost the image, then **do not** post the image.  Just because an image is in a Google search or in someone's blog does not mean it is freely available.
2. If the image is not copyrighted or you do have permission, then go ahead and post it, but be sure to give credit to your source and the creator of the image (especially if they are 2 different people).

And lastly, do not just provide a link to the image unless you answer can stand on its own without the link.  This is the same as any answer that links to another resource, whether a tool, a block of code, a blog entry, or a picture.  If the answer requires people to be able to see the resource in order to understand the answer, then the answer is not a good one.  The information needs to be full contained in the answer.  In short, links to off-site resources should only support the answer not be a key component of the answer.

Suggested Reading (about link only answers): [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)